# Aplicar Trigger por código PHP

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, trigger

Estoy generando un proyecto en Wordpress en donde los usuario deben contestar unas evaluaciones que se almacenan en una tabla (nombre de la tabla: wp_stm_lms_user_answers) propia de un plugin externo , pero requiero que esta información se inserte en una de mis tablas (wp_v_respuestas_estudiantes) ya que requiero obtener un informe y realizar algunos cálculos, para ello había creado el siguiente trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
`insert_answers_students` 
AFTER INSERT ON `wp_stm_lms_user_answers`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 insert into wp_v_respuestas_estudiantes(
     re_user_id
     , re_course_id
     , re_quiz_id
     , re_question_id
     , re_user_answer
     , re_correct_answer
     , re_equivalencia
     , re_tipo_evaluacion
     , re_answer
 ) 
values (
new.user_id
, new.course_id
, new.quiz_id
, new.question_id
, new.user_answer_id
,new.correct_answer
,(SELECT 
  case when user_answer='Siempre' then 5
    when user_answer='Casi siempre' then 4
    when user_answer='Algunas veces' then 3
    when user_answer='Casi nunca ' then 2
    when user_answer='Nunca' then 1
    else user_answer end as calificacion
  from wp_stm_lms_user_answers
  where user_answer_id=new.user_answer_id
)
,(select ev_pk from wp_v_informe_conf where pk_question=new.question_id)
, new.user_answer)
```

Esto me funcionó muy bien en mi local, no obstante al intentar implementarlo en el servidor en el Cpanel no me fue posible por temas de permisos, por lo que requiero emular este trigger por código, es decir que cada x tiempo el sistema revise si hay un registro nuevo y si lo encuentra lo inserte en mi tabla.

La verdad he intentado hacerlo pero no me ha funcionado, creé una función para este objetivo, pero la verdad no tengo ni idea de como realizar este procedimiento.

Les agradecería mucho si me pudieran orientar sobre como lo podría hacer.

Un saludo y de antemano gracias.

Comment: revisa el codigo del plugin y donde hace la inserción busca una línea que diga `do_action('el_nombre_de_un_action')` por ejemplo hay un action luego de un update  en [lms/classes/lesson.php línea 80](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system/trunk/_core/lms/classes/lesson.php#L80) a partir de ahí podes hacer un [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) en el child theme y recuperar la info

Comment: Suponiendo que la llave primaria es compuesta, puedes hacer un INSERT-SELECT a partir de las respuestas faltantes: `SELECT ua.* FROM wp_stm_lms_user_answers ua LEFT JOIN wp_v_respuestas_estudiante re ON re.re_user_id = ua.user_id AND re.re_course_id = ua.course_id AND re.re_quiz_id = ua.quiz_id AND re.re_question_id = ua.question_id WHERE re.re_user_id is null`.

Comment: tienes acceso a los cron??

Comment: @aloMalbarez, gracias, pero no quiero trabajar en el tema, me ha pasado que cuando trabajo allí y se hace alguna actualización del mismo se sobreescribe y se pierde lo trabajado, sin embargo gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @sal, gracias estoy probando si de esta forma podría hacerlo

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 si lo tengo, cree un Cron de prueba y me permitió crearlo, pero no sabría como estructurar el archivo php

Comment: un archivo comun y corriente de php ... con codigo php que hace lo que dices que quieres ... en el cron pones el path de ese archivo para que se ejecute cada X cantida de tiempo ... eso no tiene mucha ciencia ...

Comment: @Juliandonadobarriga es para evitar eso que se crea un [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) o tema hijo. Usando actions/filters evitas que deje de funcionar si cambia el prefix, el nombre de la tabla o el storage del plugin